# Shall/will; should/would

Tags: grammar, word-usage

Let's try this again.

Recently a very frustrated someone asked me, "What is this shall and will?  How to know when to use shall and will?

I proceded to give him a mini lecture on how shall/will used be be conjugated back in the day, explaining that the usage that existed when I was a child has been replaced by something more relaxed.  He persisted in his frustration and asked me when the change came about.  That is why I am posting the following question.

The nuns taught me that shall/will is conjugated this way:

I shall

you will

he will

we shall

you will

they will

Similarly, should/would is conjugated this way:

I should

you would

he would

we should

you would

they would

My specific question was, how long ago was I shall / we shall and I should / we should replaced by I will / we will and I would / we would in the popular vernacular?

Had I got it wrong back in the fourth grade, I could have expected my knuckles to get rapped

I've deleted the editorializing comment I made (apologies).  Now all I want is to get a timeline for when the accepted usage changed.  Wikipedia does not supply this information, nor does the AP style handbook.